# jupyter notebook is in python 2.7 even anaconda environment shows version is python 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-3.6

I need to use python 3.6 for a project but when I created an environment in anaconda with python 3.6, and activate that environment, I still get python 2.7 when I open jupyter notebook. Please see below:

[image]

```
Last login: Mon Apr 27 23:18:46 on ttys000
LPT-010557-PU:~ l576$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
py36                     /Users/l576/.conda/envs/py36
base                  *  /anaconda2
deeplearning             /anaconda2/envs/deeplearning
tensorflow               /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow
tensorflow_env           /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow_env

LPT-010557-PU:~ l576$ source activate py36
(py36) LPT-010557-PU:~ l576$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
py36                  *  /Users/l576/.conda/envs/py36
base                     /anaconda2
deeplearning             /anaconda2/envs/deeplearning
tensorflow               /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow
tensorflow_env           /anaconda2/envs/tensorflow_env

(py36) LPT-010557-PU:~ l576$ jupyter notebook
[I 23:24:50.455 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from 
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 23:24:50.455 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /anaconda2/share/jupyter/lab
[I 23:24:50.463 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/l576
[I 23:24:50.463 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 23:24:50.463 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 23:24:50.464 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7485fa34bd9851e5bbf698950f7689113f526f96551c1158
[I 23:24:50.464 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 23:24:50.465 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=7485fa34bd9851e5bbf698950f7689113f526f96551c1158
[I 23:24:50.579 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
```

Comment: You can first check `which jupyter`, and btw did you install jupyter in this env?

Comment: oh.. it turns out I did not install jupyter in this env.. thanks a lot